# How to process a request with empty content-type and content-length header

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, content-type

A software that i'm using(https://camlytics.com/)  sends a request to a webhook whenever a particular event occurs, now i want to process that request but the problem is that the request is sent with the following headers as empty

- content-length
- content-type

Due to this reason my node code completely ignores the request. I have verified that the request is actually being sent via creating a webhook @ webhook.site.

I fail to understand if webhook.site can show and process that request, why cant node do it? the code easily processes all other get requests.

Would appreciate if someone could either

- help me process the request as in make it accessible via the code
- if somone with experience on camlytics help me configure it in such a way that i can configure the headers of the request. 
  I have tried this on serverless azure function which is supposed to trigger for all HTTP requests but event that doesnt trigger, neither does it trigger on my local NODE server.

[This is the request details that webhook.site shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7i41.png)

Comment: While this is an excellent question written well, it's also very broad. If you show us what you have so far we can help debug.

Comment: @JosephCho added request details from webhook.site to the original question

Answer (score 1):

Camlytics webhooks seem to work OK if you add `Content-Type application/json` to the Headers properties box for the HTTP Response node.